# Initializing generics in Java

Tags: java, initialization

Suppose I have a class called `NodeList` with two fields, called `value` (type `Object`) and `index` (type `int`). `NodeList` implements an interface called `Copiable`, with a single method called `copyNotSyncronized()`.

I want the `NodeList` version of `copyNotSincronyzed()` to recognize if `this.value` implements `Copiable` and, if that happens:

1. Use `copyNotSincronyzed()` on `this.value` and...
2. ...build a new `NodeList` object that have `this.value.copyNotSincronyzed()` as field `value`.

I tried to write the code and drown in red underlining. After that I know two things: my Eclipse **really** hate me and I still have to undestand how to use generics in Java.

What mistakes did I do?

```
public class NodeList implements Copiable {

    int index;
    Object value;

public NodeList(Object value, int index){
[...]
}

NodeList copyNotSincronyzed(){
  NodeList copied;
  if(  onArray.findPositionsOfElement(this.value.getClass().getInterfaces() , this.getClass().getInterfaces()[0])[0] !=-1   )
     // aka if this.value implements the same interface of this class (aka Copiable)
     {
// Following line features three errors: 
   // Incorrect number of arguments for type Class<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <T, Copiable>
   // T cannot be resolved to a type
   // Syntax error on token "implements", , expected
     Class<T implements Copiable> copiedObject = this.value;


     copiedObject=copiedObject.copyNotSincronyzed();
     copied = new NodeList( copiedObject , this.index );
     }
   else copied = new NodeList(this.value, this.index);

   }  

}
```

Comment: `Copiable` is a typo. Did you mean to call it `Copyable`? (edit) `Sincronyzed` too. lolz

Comment: Err... yes. Sorry, english is not my first language.

Answer (score 2):

this.value is of type `Object`. And you are trying to put it into a type `Class<T implements Copiable>`. The compiler does not know how to do that so you are getting a compilation error.

In order to make this check you should use the instanceof operator, combine with a cast, like this:

```
if (this.value instanceof Copiable){ // check that the instance implements an interface
    Copiable asCopiable = (Copiable)this.value; // safely cast to the appropriate type
}
```

Note that your problem does not have anything to do with generics.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a type, like a class. Therefore, when another class implements it, any object of that class can be used polymorphically as that interface.

Which means that you can check if that object implements that interface simply by using `x instanceof Y`. It's an operator that tells you whether x "is a" Y, and Y can be either a class or an interface.

Once you established that your object implements the type, you can cast it into the type of the interface using parentheses.

For the code itself I refer you to the answer given by Vitaliy.

Answer (score 0):

Java has an interface `Clonable` that lets you clone unlinked (unsynchronized) objects through a method `Object clone()`. There is a lot of controversy around this and the bottomline is that it's discouraged.

A widely accepted way of creating copies of objects is by using a *copy-constructor*. This will not work for general `Object` since you don't know the run-time class in advance. In this case `Clonable`-like structure may still prove useful.

Because `Clonable` is legacy, it doesn't have generics. Let's make `Copyable` as a replacement for `Clonable` (and rename `clone()` as `copyNotSyncronyzed()`)

```
public interface Copyable<T> {
    T copyNotSyncronyzed();
}

public class NodeList implements Copyable<NodeList> {
    private int     index; // make final too unless you plan to change it at some point
    private Object  value; // make final too unless you plan to change it at some point

    public NodeList(final Object value, final int index) {
        this.value = value;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public NodeList copyNotSyncronyzed() {
        if (value instanceof Copyable) {
            Object copiedObject = ((Copyable<?>)this.value).copyNotSyncronyzed();

            return new NodeList(copiedObject, this.index);
        } else
            return new NodeList(this.value, this.index);
    }
}
```

The last question is if you are really happy with this structure, as it copies linked `value` instances if they are not `Copyable`. This can potentially create dangerous situations since code calling `copyNotSyncronyzed()` may expect it to be comppletely unrelated to the original.

For example, if value is an `int[]`. You create a copy using `copyNotSyncronyzed()`, then you change some values in the array, and lo and behold, the values in the array of the original object are changed too.